# Can you make lava that continues flowing on a flat surface indefinitely?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to make it so that when you place a lava bucket it doesn't stop flowing? I'm just doing this for fun but I would like to know. I would prefer if the answer could use something like /give and be used in a command block because I want to make it so you can just press a button to give it to the player. Any other method is fine, though.

Comment: Do you mean that if you place the lava on flat ground it will continue expanding beyond the 3 block limit? I don't believe so, although you could write a function for it using commands. This function would just check if there were more air blocks to the side of the lava and at the same or lower y value and if there were, it would set the block to lava. It would then do the same thing at the placed block of lava, recursively changing all available air blocks at a lesser or equal y  level to lava.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Alright, thank you for telling me. :D

Comment: No problem. I put an answer explaining the datapack option in more depth.

Comment: I believe that water worked like that in a very early version. Obviously you can't import it to newer versions though

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in vanilla, but a datapack mimicking similar behavior is possible.

First, setup a scoreboard objective tracking the placement of lava buckets. When a player's score increments (meaning they have placed a lava bucket) use raycasting to determine which block the lava is at. Then, run a recursive function at that block that checks for a suitable (adjacent at a lower or equal y level) air/cave_air block to set to lava, and then executes the recursive function at those newly placed blocks. If the lava is placed in a bowl or underground in a closed cave system it will stop spreading, but if you placed it on a flat world it would instantly cover the entire loaded world in lava.

Comment: I'm going to work on that now! Thank you!